# Remove space in between doctype in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, saxon

While transforming XML to XML using XSLT I have included doctype in output XML. But a line break is created in the output XML doctype declaration.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="book3.dtd" doctype-public="-//Atypon//DTD test//EN" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
```

output XML after using XSLT:

```
<!DOCTYPE book
  PUBLIC "-//Atypon//DTD test//EN" "book3.dtd">
```

Space and line break are created in between book and public in doctype declaration.

I need the doctype declaration in a single line.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: So why exactly do you need that doctype declaration in a single line?

Comment: yes martin. i need that declaration in single line

Comment: This seems to depend on the XSLT processor. `Saxon` outputs this in two lines and `xsltproc` in one line as desired. What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: we are using saxon

Comment: Which version and edition exactly of Saxon do you use? PE and EE I think have support for `saxon:line-length` http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html, try whether setting it to a high value avoids the line break inside the doctype declaration.

Answer (score 2):

When you say you "need" it to be on one line, this means that you must be processing the resulting XML using a parser that attaches significance to things (like ignorable whitespace) that should be considered insignficant.

The correct solution to your problem is to process XML only with conformant XML parsers, then you won't need to try and tweak the serialized format to fit with the restrictions your non-conformant parser imposes.

However, the Saxon serializer is designed to be customized if you really have to. Call `Configuration.setSerializerFactory()` to register a subclass of `SerializerFactory` which overrides the `newXMLEmitter()` method to create a subclass of `XMLEmitter`, and in your subclass of `XMLEmitter`, override the `writeDocType()` method to format the DOCTYPE declaration in the way you want it.