# SAX Transformer and end of line after <?xml ... ?>

Tags: java, xml, sax

To write my xml code I use the following code:

```
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;
...
XMLOutputFactory xMLOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamWriter writer = xMLOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(stringWriter);
writer.writeStartDocument("UTF-8", "1.0");
writer.writeCharacters("\n");
//I tried also writer.writeCharacters(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
writer.writeStartElement("settings");
...
```

To transform one line xml to multiline normal xml format I use the following code:

```
public String transform(final String xml) throws XMLStreamException, TransformerException {
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), new StreamResult(writer));
    return writer.toString();
}
```

And this is the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><settings>
   ...
</settings>
```

As you see the `<settings` is on the first line. How can I make `<settings>` move to the second line to get the following result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
   ...
</settings>
```

How to do it?

Comment: It's always useful to say which XSLT processor you are using. (The fact that one of your serialization parameters is Xalan-specific gives a clue, but is not hard evidence).

Comment: @Michael Kay I added imports. Or I don't understand you. Didn't I provide necessary information?

Comment: OK, if you weren't aware that there is more than one XSLT processor that implements the JAXP interface, then you're probably using the default one that comes with the JDK, which effectively answers the question.

Comment: @Michael Kay I see. But it answers your question, but not mine :). From your profile I read that you are xml specialist. Can you give any hint? I don't understand why such simple task as to write xml file using the default implementation makes such `end of line` problem. Only I have such problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you are using the built-in XSLT processor that comes with Java. That's an XSLT 1.0 processor, so we need to look to the XSLT 1.0 specification.

This is what XSLT 1.0 says about indent="yes":

> If the indent attribute has the value yes, then the xml output method
>   may output whitespace in addition to the whitespace in the result tree
>   (possibly based on whitespace stripped from either the source document
>   or the stylesheet) in order to indent the result nicely; if the indent
>   attribute has the value no, it should not output any additional
>   whitespace. The default value is no. The xml output method should use
>   an algorithm to output additional whitespace that ensures that the
>   result if whitespace were to be stripped from the output using the
>   process described in [3.4 Whitespace Stripping] with the set of
>   whitespace-preserving elements consisting of just xsl:text would be
>   the same when additional whitespace is output as when additional
>   whitespace is not output.

That's all rather convoluted but the bottom line is that the processor MAY output a newline at the point where you want it, but is under no obligation to do so.

If you use Saxon as your XSLT processor, then it does output a newline at this point.

But you haven't said why this newline is so important to you. You describe not having it as a "problem", but why is it a problem? If you parse the generated document using a standard XML parser then any newline at this point will be ignored. There is one case where it makes a difference, namely if the XML you generate is used as an external parsed entity incorporated into some larger document. But for that case you definitely DON'T want the newline (which is perhaps why Xalan doesn't output it).

**NOTE**: See also [Remove space in between doctype in XML using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171974/remove-space-in-between-doctype-in-xml-using-xslt) where the user this time is complaining about newlines in the serialized output that in this case aren't wanted. If you care about such differences between alternative serializations of the same document, which won't affect the way any conformant parser handles the document, then (a) you're probably going to have to write your own serializer, (b) you're going to lose one of the major benefits of XML which is the availability of lots of conformant tools, and (c) you're doing something wrong: probably using a non-conformant parser (or no parser at all) to process the generated XML.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer but it doesn't give the solution. The reason why it is `problem` for me is that the system administrator of our client says that is a problem, that's why I have to solve it. Besides the application must generate many different xml files maybe this is the reason they want normal xml files.

Comment: Besides, let me ask you the following. I am not XML expert and after your post I had to read about XSLT and XSL in Wiki. I don't need any of them! I just want to write some data to XML file from java object fields. That's all. Why are you talking about XSLT processor in your answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if we're going to help you solve this then we need to know why it's a problem. The most common reason on this forum for people to be fussy about how XML is formatted is that they are processing the XML incorrectly (typically with a homebrew parser), and if that's the case then you must resist the pressure to generate the particular format they want, and encourage them to process the XML correctly. The whole point about XML is that it's a standard, and you only get the benefits of XML if both the producers and consumers conform to the standards.

Comment: The reason we are talking about XSLT is that you have chosen to use an XSLT processor to serialize your XML data. You're not actually using XSLT itself, but rather you're taking advantage of the fact that XSLT processors give you a lot of control over serialization - though not quite enough in your case.

Comment: I googled for xml file and took a look at the images. In all of them root element is not at the first line (where <? xml ...?>). So, the requirements of the client can be called reasonable. They pay money and they want to get `normal` xml file.  Normal is not that only follow specs but what is usual and good for people who work with it.

Comment: No, the requirements of the client are totally unreasonable. But if you really want to keep an unreasonable client happy, try serializing using Saxon.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't agree with you. They requirements are totally reasonable - they pay money and want to get normal product for use. The problem is not in their requirements, the problem is the JDK developers didn't think this moment and this is absolutely JDK developers mistake. Because of their mistake the easiest use makes users post questions like this and waste precious time.

Comment: They clearly haven't understood why they are using XML in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked with indent and XML `standalone="yes"`.

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes")
```

Of course, however, this requires your client or application to tolerate the standalone declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple way to achieve what you need is to modify the last line of your code example in the following way:

```
return writer.toString().replaceFirst(">", ">\n");
```